# How to compute the ifft of a constant value?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, ifft, nyquist, inverse

I am clearly missing something obvious here because I am trying to do something that ought to be very simple: compute the ifft of a continuous signal.

My understanding is that the ifft of a continuous signal should be a sinc function. Is this intuition correct?

MATLAB implementation:

```
N = 10000; %number of samples
fNyq = 0.5; %nyquist frequency
fs = 2*fNyq; %sample rate
fq = 0:1/N:fNyq-1/N; %frequencies
t = fs:fs:N-1; %times

fAxis = [-fliplr(fq) fq(2:end)]; %conjugate symmetry

G = ones(length(fAxis),1); %constant value 

g = ifft(G);

plot(t,g)
```

This results in g zero everywhere except at the first time sample where g = 1.

Is this a case of needing to pad or taper/window the spectrum prior to ifft? Any explanation for what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sinc function (extended to infinity) is an ideal lowpass filter.

Its FFT, then, ideally, is a string of identical numbers, *except the numbers corresponding to frequencies above the cutoff would be zero.*

So, take your string of constant numbers, zero out numbers above a certain cutoff (and their mirrors above Nyquist), *then* iFFT and you should get an approximation of sinc.

If you don't zero out any numbers, you are not lowpassing at any frequency and are representing the single impulse (as you can see).